# Motionblur on Cornerpin node?

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes, motion-blur

after writing a script to import cornerpin data from Nuke, I just realized that there is no motion blur. Is there a way to turn it on, or is it just not supported?
Thanks

Comment: *Plane Track Deform* node has a *Motion Blur* option if that's what you mean...

Comment: That's exactly what I mean, thanks... why doesn't it exist in the cornerpin node?